# Apply jumphost's .bashrc to server during ssh from client?

Tags: bash, ssh, netcat

With the following topology:

```
    +----------+   ssh -J   +--------+       +--------------+
    |clienthost| =========> |jumphost| ====> |restrictedhost|
    +----------+            +--------+       +--------------+
                            .bashrc  - - - - - > .bashrc
```

This successfully allows me to ssh into `restrictedhost` :

```
ssh -oProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p me@jumphost" me@restrictedhost
```

and results in an uncustomized bash shell:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-45-generic x86_64)
Last login: Mon Nov 12 16:23:06 2018 from 10.250.20.3
me@restrictedhost:~$
```

What I want is to carry my dotfile from `jumphost` (not the client, that's more complicated) to `restrictedhost` so that, among other things, I get my personalized prompt:

```
bash Mon Nov 12  16:36:21 ~/ me@MacBook-Pro>
```

How can I apply `jumphost:/tmp/.bashrc` file to the shell at `restrictedhost`?

#### What I do know

1. When there is no jumphost involved, this gives me my bash customizations:

   ```
   ssh me@unrestricted  "echo "$(cat ${HOME}/.bashrc | base64 -w 0)" | base64 --decode > /tmp/${USER}_bashrc; cd /tmp/; bash --rcfile /tmp/${USER}_bashrc"
   ```
2. If I directly apply 1. to the jump, I get no command prompt (or other bash customizations) at all:

   ```
   ssh -oProxyCommand="sshpass -p Empty$paces ssh -W %h:%p devteam@man1-pqa" devteam@queue1-pqa "bash --rcfile /tmp/_bashrc"
   ```

Comment: Cross-posted because the other one is getting downvoted and will probably get closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Escape pipes, redirects and semi colons

```
ssh -t me@jumphost "ssh -t  me@restrictedhost echo "$(~/.bashrc | base64 -w 0)" \| base64 --decode \> /tmp/my_bashrc \; bash --rcfile /tmp/my_bashrc"
```

Explanation:

- you need to escape pipes, redirects and semicolons so that the jumphost doesn't interpret them. You want the restricted host to interpret them. The jumphost should pass everything verbatim.
- you echo the local `.bashrc` contents on the restricted host, escaped as base64 so you don't have to deal with newlines (or any special characters). Thank goodness for base 64!
- actually this copies the .bashrc file from the CLIENT, not the jumphost (which is even better).

#### sshpass

```
sshpass -p jumphostpas$word autossh -M0 -t jumphostusername@jumphostname "sshpass -p restrictedhostpas\\\$word autossh -M0 -t  restrictedhostusername@restrictedhostname echo "$(cat ~/.bashrc | base64 -w 0)" \| base64 \\\-\\\-decode \> /tmp/my_bashrc   \; bash \\\-\\\-rcfile /tmp/my_bashrc "
```

#### key binding (ZSH)

If you want to make this a ZSH key binding, do this:

```
bindkey -s "^[K" 'sshpass -p passwordjumphost autossh -M0 -t usernamejumphost@jumphostname "sshpass -p pas\\\\\\$wordrestrictedhost autossh -M0 -t  usernamerestrictedhost@restrictedhostname echo "$(cat ~/.bashrc | base64 -w 0)" \\| base64 \\\\\\-\\\\\\-decode \\> /tmp/my_bashrc   \\; bash \\\\\\-\\\\\\-rcfile /tmp/my_bashrc "'
```